# set up dtm and analytics on a new website

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I have a 3 page website. I want to know how many unique visitors visit each page of the website. That is how many unique visitors in page A, and from page how many reach page B and from page B how many reach page C.

I am unable to determine or understand how the `eVars` and `success events` will be set in this scenario.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished quickly using the default path reports in Adobe Analytics.

This "out of the box" report will show you a "fall out" of visitors who started on page A went to page B and then on to page C. No eVars, props or events are needed for this.

The report will also show you the percentage of visitors who didn't complete the specified path as well.

Setting the page name with DTM will be helpful but is not required because the URL is used as the PN if it isn't set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On Page A, there is a selection for Male and Female. How can I further segregate the report to know the Unique Male and Female Visitors on each page?? Can you please guide?