# set up dtm and analytics on a new website - unique visitors

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I have a 3 page website. I want to know how many unique visitors visit each page of the website. That is how many unique visitors in page A, and from page how many reach page B and from page B how many reach page C.

But, on page A, there is an option for Male and Female. I want to further know how many Male Unique Visitors and how many Female Unique Visitors visited on each page.

I am unable to determine or understand how the `eVars` and `success events` will be set in this scenario.

Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about google analytics tracking and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: its related to coding and related to analytics

Comment: The internet doesn't magically know whether visitors are male or female. The only way that is possible is if your site requires them to login and that info is part of their account profile and they (truthfully) provide that info and then your site exposes it on the page (e.g. outputs to a data layer variable) for you to reference in DTM to push to an Adobe Analytics variable.

Comment: @CrayonViolent, i wanted to add on to this question [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848469/set-up-dtm-and-analytics-on-a-new-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using DTM then you can use page load rules to see how many people hit each page. You can use a custom event that fires on page b if the referrer is page a or whatever combination you want. You can use an event based rule that fires when they submit their form (I'm guess you have some sort of form) that is collecting their gender. Gender would go into an evar, I'd also store the referrer in an eVar if you're interested in how people travel around your site and then use some metrics in the adobe dashboard to get the segments that you want.

Those are all very simple things to do. If you still are having issues, you should check out the [forums](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/forum/reporting) or [docs](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/rules.html)